# using glue to get data from ec2 mysql to redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to pull a table from a mysql database on an ec2 instance through to s3 to query in redshift.  My current pipeline is I crawl the mysql database table with aws glue crawler to get the schema in the data catalog.  Then I set up an aws etl job to pull the data in to an s3 bucket.  Then I again crawl the data in the s3 bucket with another crawler to get the schema for the data in the s3 bucket in to the data catalog and then run the script below in redshift query window to pull the schema in to redshift.  It seems like a lot of steps.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  For example is there a way to re-use the schema from the first crawler so I don't have to crawl the data twice.  It's the same table and columns.

script:

```
create external schema schema1
from data catalog database 'database1' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::228276746111:role/sfada'
region 'us-west-2'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Comment: did you consider using AWS DMS with mysql as source and S3 or Redshift as target?

Comment: @JonScott Thank you for getting back to me on this, wouldn't I still need to crawl the data in s3 after I'd used DMS to get it to s3?

Comment: yes but only once unless something changes? - do you need to keep a copy in s3 - hy not go straight to redshift?